# How to globally normalize unicode strings coming in HTTP Requests?

Tags: php, laravel, unicode

How do I globally normalize unicode strings in PHP, say for instance using Laravel?

Thing is I work in a multilingual environment, and in order to do comparison and sorting of strings sanely I need to normalize strings. I was wondering if there was a way for me to do this globally, so I don't need to a bunch of calls for doing normalization.

Comment: I didn't use them yet. But I think, middleware could be your hero: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Comment: Please define what you mean by "normalize".

Comment: @Sammitch I mean doing `normalizer_normalize` or `Normalizer::normalize`